# How to bind method interface in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, interface, ioc-container, lumen

[image]

How to bind instance to ValidationInterface by method

Comment: A screenshot of code is not code. Also you should look into [form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: I just modify, I'm in lumen

Comment: Typehint the correct class instead of the interface. You gain nothing by typehinting the interface and then doing all sorts of other things to switch the classes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because it will try to "new up" an interface which is not how an interface works.

You need to implement that interface to a concrete implementation bind the interface to container like:

```
app()->bind(Interface::class, Concrete::class);
```

So all the time you method inject the interface the IOC container knows that when `Interface` its called return `Concrete` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also in the app.php file.

```
    $app->bind(ServiceInterface::class, ServiceConcrete::class);
```

And now, you can do this in your controller:

```
private $service;

public function __construct(ServiceInterface $service)
{
    $this->service = $service;
}
```